# How to load a main .scss file into Webpack 3.6~ and React

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have spent the last couple hours trying to get an existing group of `SCSS` files to work in a React project, but I can't seem to get it to use them.

I was previously running a fairly minimalist Webpack config with CDN supplied styles, so I haven't had to go full custom yet.

1. My main problem is the CSS is not working.
2. This project is currently compiling without issue.

Here are my current files:

**./webpack.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      },
      // {
      //     test: /\.css$/,
      //     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      // },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'css/[name]-[chunkhash].css',
          disable: false,
          allChunks: true
      }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 80
  }
};
```

**./postcss.config.js**

This is just experimental garbage. I will come back to it later.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

**./index.html**

I don't have anything to do with CSS or SCSS in my root html file, which may be part of the issue. I don't know what to do though if so.

**./src/index.js**

```
// ... ✂ ...

const Root = () => (
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

**./src/components/App.js**

```
export default ({ match: { url } }) => {
  return (
    <div id="container">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${url}login`} component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path={`${url}logout`} component={LogOut} />
        <Route path={`${url}signup`} component={SignUp} />
        <Route path={`${url}dashboard`} component={requireAuth(Dashboard)} />
        <Route path={`${url}profile/edit`} component={requireAuth(ProfileEdit)} />
        <Route path={`${url}profile`} component={requireAuth(Profile)} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**./src/components/auth/LoginForm.js**

```
// ... ✂ ...

import '../../../styles/app.scss'

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="full-row">what</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginForm
```

This above file is where I am manifesting the problem. You can see it has `className="row"` and `className="full-row"` being used in it, and I am importing `'../../../styles/app.scss'` which has that CSS in it:

```
.full-row {
  @include flex(column);
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 57.6rem;
  background: yellow;
}

.row {
  @include flex(column);
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 102.4rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

All I want is to see that yellow and pink so I know the SCSS is hooked up.

> Is my webpack.config.js file screwed up?
>
> Is the way I am trying to import SCSS in LoginForm.js incorrect?
>
> Does my index.html file need anything to make this work?
>
> I have not compiled any SCSS. I am trying to rely on Webpack to help me there.

I need some pointers based on what I have so far.

Comment: Do you insert link to the stylesheets  in your index.html?

Comment: No I didn't. I actually just solved it 15 mins ago by doing that :)

Comment: I also changed my webpack config file a bit based on what is shown on this page: http://jpsierens.com/tutorial-react-redux-webpack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by removing this line from my `LoginForm.js` file:

```
import '../../../styles/app.scss'
```

and putting it into my `./src/index.js` file like this:

```
import '../styles/app.scss'
```

Those `../` were a code smell waiting to happen anyway.

I also updated my webpack config file to replace that `.scss` portion with what you see here:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'css/[name]-[chunkhash].css',
          disable: false,
          allChunks: true
      }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 80
  }
};
```

I found that on this webpage: http://jpsierens.com/tutorial-react-redux-webpack/ and after, Webpack threw an error about deprecated loader syntax, which made me remember that the solution for that is to explicitly declare them.

If anyone encounters that, change this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css!sass?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
},
```

to this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
},
```

I currently don't know what this `hash` part is, but I imagine it has some bearing on cache invalidation, so I will keep it and research later.

Please leave a comment if you see anything concerning.